# RAID 10 only show half array size

Tags: linux, centos7, raid10

I setup RAID 10 with 4 hdd (4x 2TB), but after raid process I can only see 2TB space. Please advice how to fix regarding space problem?

Below result from df -h only show 2TB harddisk rather than 4 TB

```
[root@dc1 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md125      1.9T  1.7T  208G  89% /
devtmpfs         16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            16G  1.6G   15G  11% /run
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md126      468M  222M  247M  48% /boot
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0
```

Below result from lsblk

```
[root@dc1 ~]# lsblk
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE   MOUNTPOINT
sda         8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1      8:1    0   1.9G  0 part
│ └─md127   9:127  0   3.7G  0 raid10 [SWAP]
├─sda2      8:2    0   239M  0 part
│ └─md126   9:126  0   474M  0 raid10 /boot
└─sda3      8:3    0 930.6G  0 part
  └─md125   9:125  0   1.8T  0 raid10 /
sdb         8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sdb1      8:17   0   1.9G  0 part
│ └─md127   9:127  0   3.7G  0 raid10 [SWAP]
├─sdb2      8:18   0   239M  0 part
│ └─md126   9:126  0   474M  0 raid10 /boot
└─sdb3      8:19   0 930.6G  0 part
  └─md125   9:125  0   1.8T  0 raid10 /
sdc         8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sdc1      8:33   0   1.9G  0 part
│ └─md127   9:127  0   3.7G  0 raid10 [SWAP]
├─sdc2      8:34   0   239M  0 part
│ └─md126   9:126  0   474M  0 raid10 /boot
└─sdc3      8:35   0 930.6G  0 part
  └─md125   9:125  0   1.8T  0 raid10 /
sdd         8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sdd1      8:49   0   1.9G  0 part
│ └─md127   9:127  0   3.7G  0 raid10 [SWAP]
├─sdd2      8:50   0   239M  0 part
│ └─md126   9:126  0   474M  0 raid10 /boot
└─sdd3      8:51   0 930.6G  0 part
  └─md125   9:125  0   1.8T  0 raid10 /
```

below result from fdisk -l

```
[root@dc1 ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00086703

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048     3911679     1954816   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2   *     3911680     4401151      244736   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3         4401152  1955977215   975788032   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0006a08e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048     3911679     1954816   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2   *     3911680     4401151      244736   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3         4401152  1955977215   975788032   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md127: 3999 MB, 3999268864 bytes, 7811072 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1048576 bytes


Disk /dev/md126: 497 MB, 497025024 bytes, 970752 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1048576 bytes


Disk /dev/md125: 1998.1 GB, 1998143356928 bytes, 3902623744 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1048576 bytes


Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0008f346

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048     3911679     1954816   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdc2   *     3911680     4401151      244736   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdc3         4401152  1955977215   975788032   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdd: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0007820d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1            2048     3911679     1954816   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdd2   *     3911680     4401151      244736   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdd3         4401152  1955977215   975788032   fd  Linux raid autodetect
```

Many thanks for your information and advice.

Comment: You are mounting `/dev/md125` which is 1.8T. I suggest that you mount `/dev/md127` which is 3.7T.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as though (from the fdisk -l output) you have only allocated about 1T (930.6G) of disk space to sd3 on each disk.

- The total number of sectors on the disk (first line): 3907029168 sectors
- The last sector allocated on each disk (last line, sda3): 1955977215 (sectors)

.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors

Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00086703

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048     3911679     1954816   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2   *     3911680     4401151      244736   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3         4401152  1955977215   975788032   fd  Linux raid autodetect
```

If you drop the RAID array, expand sd3 to fill the disk (perhaps using gparted?), and then rebuild the RAID array, I expect you will see the full size.

I hope this helps.